# CronJob is failing inside the container while using docker-desktop in windows 10

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, cron, docker-desktop

I am working on a application where I am running multiple containers using docker-compose.yml. All the containers are successfully up. One of the container is having a cron file with the following contents:

```
* * * * * sshpass -p root ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@myserver"./script.sh" > /proc/1/fd/1 2> /proc/1/fd/2
```

whenever this cron job is trying to run I am getting the below error in intelliJ console:

```
cron_1                                  | crond: USER root pid  35 cmd sshpass -p root ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@myserver"./script.sh" > /proc/1/fd
/1 2> /proc/1/fd/2
: nonexistent directory                 | /bin/sh: can't create /proc/1/fd/2
```

When I logged in container cli, I can see that directory location exists:-
[image: Container File location]

It's wokring fine on ubuntu but not on windows.

below is the output of docker version

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.7
 Version:           20.10.2
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        2291f61
 Built:             Mon Dec 28 16:14:16 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.2
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       8891c58
  Built:            Mon Dec 28 16:15:28 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Can anyone please help how to make the cron run inside container ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure line endings in your cron file set to Linux/UNIX